# Dropping 120 volts AC to 100 volts AC

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer

I bought a rare Sansui SE-88 equalizer from Japan without realizing it operates on 100 volts AC,instead of the standard 120 U.S. voltage. OOPS! Not finding an original transformer with a 120 volt AC primary for the U.S.,and seeing 120 to 100 volt AC converters are bulky and expensive--could I just use a choke in series with the line to drop the 120 AC going in, down to the required 100 volts AC going into the Japanese transformer primary?

Comment: I don't think so. The drop would depend on how much the equalizer draws. It would be clunky, but you could use a variac.

Comment: [The manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/696718/Sansui-771.html?page=30#manual) says there is a voltage selector behind the name plate on the rear panel.

Answer (score 11):

You can do a subtraction with a transformer.

[image]

With a 120V:20V transformer, there will be 20V AC on the secondary. If you wire the secondary in series with the incoming 120V, it will either add or subtract 20V depending on the polarity.

This will be less bulky than an isolation transformer because the whole transformer doesn't need to be rated for the VA rating of your load. Current drawn by the load only goes through the secondary, which needs to be rated for the current, but not the power. So if the load draws 100V 1A (100VA), you need a 20V 1A transfomer (20VA).

You can also wire a transformer as an autotransformer (like a variac).

[image]

In this case you need a 100V:20V transformer, which is the same as a 120V:24V transformer. As above the 24V winding should be rated for the load current.

Answer (score 6):

Your best approach could be an autotransformer.

You can repurpose a 120v to 24v transformer rated as low as 1/5 of the load power rating and connect its primary and secondary windings in series.

You will get either something abour 100v or something above 120v across the primary. If you get 100, you are ok to go, otherwise you need to swap the terminals of one of the windings.

But first, check for 4 important things:

- does your device tolerate wider input voltage as-is? A thing of 1980s will not be 100-240v but it could easily be 100-120v
- there may be a switch somewhere, usually on the back, switching the input voltage - 100-120-220-240 or something like. It may as well be 100-110 or 100-115.
- in some cases there is no external switch, but instead some means of switching requiring opening the device, have a look inside.
- the previous owner may have did something about the problem - up to and including replacing the transformer inside.